# Get a range of values with Spring JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have an Entity class with one parameter in Spring, the parameter

```
private int value;
```

Now I have an Postgres database connected with  Spring Jpa, and I have multiple entrys with the value in the database. How can I  search for a certain range of the value from the database. For  example I want to have the values from the range 20 till 100. I know there is are methods in Jpa but none of these really didnt help me or I used them wrong:

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using JPQL and use a query like `select e from Entity e where e.value >= ?1 and e.value <= ?2`?

Comment: oh man didnt think of that to be true and thx for the help